# How do I reuse a previous matplotlib axes object in a new figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently generating multiple subplots on the single figure.  I then want to plot one of the axes objects individually in its own figure.  I don't want to have to regenerate the axes object, but reuse the axes from the first plot.  E.g.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
N = 100             # Number of elements

# Initialize x and y
xV = np.zeros([N])
for i in range(N):
    xV[i] = i
y1 = xV
y2 = xV**2

# Plot
fig, axL = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
axL[0].plot(xV, y1)
axL[1].plot(xV, y2)
plt.show()
plt.close(fig)

# Reuse axL[0] in its own plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = axL[0]     # The memory address for ax actually points to axL[0] here
plt.show()      # <-- This is EMPTY
```

The first plot works, the second plot is empty.

**Question** :

1. How do I reuse a previously used axes object in a new plot?

Comment: That is not possible with matplotlib architecture.

Comment: The recommended approach when you need a subplot a second time is to define a function that a.o. gets an ax as parameter and creates the plot. Then call that function once for each figure.

Comment: I'm sorry, what does "a.o." mean?